# Need to parse an array for a URLQueryItem

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm building an app which sends information to an API. In the documentation of the API it says the request should be send like this:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 84ec207ad0154a508f798e615a998ac1fd752926d00f955fb1df3e144cba44ab" \
  -XPOST \
  -d '{"external_sales_invoice":{"reference":"30052","contact_id":303632932854040464,"details_attributes":[{"description":"Rocking Chair","price":129.95}]}}' \
  https://moneybird.com/api/v2/123/external_sales_invoices
```

The example above is for cURL, btw. But as you can see the 'details_attribute' is an array. How do I translate this to Swift code? I've tried:

```
        let url = URL(string: "https://moneybird.com/api/v2/294775401414132869/external_sales_invoices")!
        var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "contact_id", value: "\(contactID)"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "details_attribute", value: "[{\"description\":\(description),\"price\":\(price)}]")
        ]

        let query = components.url!.query

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = Data(query!.utf8)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print(httpResponse.statusCode, "invoice")
            }
        }.resume()
```

Comment: You are mixing URL encoding and JSON. What you want, is `JSONSerialization`. Don't use `URLComponents`: `let param: [String: Any] = ["external_sales_invoice": ["reference": "30052", "contact_id":303632932854040464, "details_attributes": [ ["description":"Rocking Chair","price": 129.95] ]]]; request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])`

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much you saved my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Larme's answer worked:
I deleted my URLQueryItems and replaced it with:

```
let param: [String: Any] = ["external_sales_invoice": ["reference": "30052", "contact_id":303632932854040464, "details_attributes": [ ["description":"Rocking Chair","price": 129.95] ]]]
```

and

```
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])
```